# Confused about Makefile (C/unix)

Tags: c, unix

http://puu.sh/7OiDL.png

Ok so what does export: StackImplementation.o do? Like where does it export that to?
Also, what is gcc -l doing? I googled it and it says "gcc -l links with a library file". What's linking to the library file?
Lastly, what does "substitute a print command of your choice for lpr below" mean? What's lpr  do? and what's clean: rm -f *.o?

Comment: Your .png file isn't a very helpful way of presenting the makefile.  edit your answer to include it as text then people can cut n paste, quote it and answer your specific questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `export` is the name of a phony target.  You can say

```
% make export
```

And make will build the its dependencies.  There is no action specifying how to convert the dependencies into a file called export, and in the absence of an implicit rule, the make will stop after building the dependencies.

The `-I` to gcc is adding a path to search for include files.  You are confusing it with the `-l` option which specifies the name of a library to link (a pre-built collection of object files from which unresolved symbols can be satisfied).

The `lpr` command sends a file to the default line printer.  Again, `print` is a phony target; doing

```
% make print
```

sends the source file to the printer.

Most makefiles include a `clean` rule to delete generated files.  It is necessary when the dependencies are not properly specified, and a change to a source file does not cause the target to be built.  The `rm` command is short for remove; it deletes files.  If you do

```
% make clean
```

it will force-delete all files that end with `.o`.

Most of these targets are phony, and will not work correctly if there happen to be files with those names that are newer than their dependencies (if any). Most makes allow you to specify which targets are phony by listing them as dependencies of a super phony `.PHONY` target.  Make will then ignore the filesystem, and will always apply the rules.

Answer (score 1):

```
export:
```

this is a target named "export" and is the first target in the makefile so it will get called by default if no target is specified on the command line. Not clear to me why it is called "export" but that's the name somebody chose for it

```
export: StackImplementation.o
```

this says that export depends on StackImplementation.o so it will invoke the target StackImplementation.o when export is invoked

```
StackImplementation.o: StackImplementation.c ...
```

StackImplementaiton.o depends on the source file StackImplementation.c and the include files listed. This will run gcc which has the flag -I../Include which tells gcc to include .h files in adjacent directory "Include"

```
# substitute...
```

this is a comment indicating to change the print command lpr to some other print command if you want to

```
clean:
```

this is a common target that will delete object files with the -f option, forcing remove even if write permission is not set

Answer (score 0):

1) lpr submits files for printing. Files named on the command line are sent to the  named  printer
       (or the default destination if no destination is specified). If no files are listed on the com‐
       mand-line, lpr reads the print file from the standard input.

for more information about "lpr " use user manual of linux.

---

2)gcc -l link external library to your program if any dependency .

example::

```
gcc hello.c -o hello -lpthread -ldrm -ldrm_omap
```

---

in Make file::

```
clean:
       rm -rf *.o
```

here clean is a rule of make and when we call make clean then it will invoke rm -rf *.o to remove all  object files.